# ironpython import BeautifulSoup SystemError: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, ironpython

I am trying to get BeautifulSoup working in IronPython on Windows.

I have installed BeautifulSoup by running the install script with IronPython:

```
cd Downloads\dist\beautifulsoup4-4.3.2
ipy setup.py install
```

But when I try to import BeautifulSoup in IronPython I get an error:

```
C:\>ipy
IronPython 2.7.5 (2.7.5.0) on .NET 4.0.30319.34209 (32-bit)
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\lib\site-packages\bs4\builder\__init__.py", line 308, in <module>
SystemError: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

The offending line in `bs4\builder\__init__.py` is:

```
308: from . import _htmlparser
```

And there is a module named `_htmlparser.py` in the same directory.

Please help!

Comment: I am not familiar with IronPython but I'd guess it's missing HTMLParser from standard library. Is BeautifulSoup compatible with IronPython ?

Comment: Yes, the [source](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~leonardr/beautifulsoup/bs4/view/head:/bs4/builder/_htmlparser.py) of _htmlparser imports HTMLParser, but I do seem to have this as when I run `import HTMLParser` from the IronPython console I get no error.

Comment: Then I'd guess there is an issue with the HTMLParser library. Does IronPython have this in the site packages ?

Comment: HTML Parser seems to be OK. I edited my last comment to reflect this.

Comment: Oh, ok. Can you try importing bs4.dammit ?

Comment: No! Same error as in my question.

Comment: Cool, that's the issue. There must be a problem with unicode dammit and IronPython. Could you add some prints on bs4/dammit.py to see where exactly it raises the exception ?

Comment: No success. The error is coming from `__init__.py`, which is before anything in bs4.dammit is hit, no?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72706/discussion-between-tasos-vogiatzoglou-and-imran).